# Ionic cordova plugin not working when update chrome version 73

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic4

I am using ionic framework 4.12.0. My mobile app not working when i update chrome version 73. If i debug app project the problem is all ***cordova*** plugin not working (Error).

But if i downgrade chrome version 72 or 71. My app is no problem and running well.

Some people can help me?

Note: Ionic framework running on *webview* android. While a *webview* have in chrome browser.

Comment: To get better answers, you may need to put additional effort into your question. Tell us what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it.